# Inverse Function: unique?

Tags: functions

Is it true in general that the inverse of a function is unique if it exists? Why is this so?

*Clearly inverses in groups are unique. However, that seems not directly applicable in this  case...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a two-sided inverse, then yes. To see why assume that $f_1,f_2$ are both
two-sided inverses of $h$. Then
$$f_1 = f_1\circ (h\circ f_2) = (f_1\circ h)\circ f_2 = f_2$$

Note that this proof implies that if $h$ has a left inverse and a right inverse, then they are necessarily the same.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2=1\iff x=\pm1;\quad\sin x=0\iff x=2k\pi,\quad k\in\mathbb Z.~$ So no, they are not necessarily unique, especially if the function is periodic or [even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions), etc. If you do want uniqueness, however, then you have to separate the domain of definition into intervals of bijectivity.